# Xubuntu Live USB created with LiLi boots to Grub shell only

Tags: grub2, xubuntu, live-usb, 20.10

I used LiLi v2.9 to create a Live USB from `xubuntu-20.10-desktop-amd64.iso` but it boots just to the Grub shell. It doesn't start `xfce`.

I "burned" the USB with both FAT32 formatting and without it, to no avail.

I also tried different combinations of LiLi's advanced settings. Nothing helped.

Anything else I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### LILI USB Creator is Obsolete

As can be seen from it's internet site LILI USB Creator is obsolete and has been abandoned.

https://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/supported-linuxes

The latest version of Ubuntu mentioned on the site is Ubuntu 15.04.

Many changes to booting Live Ubuntu were made with versions 19.10, 20.04 and 20.10.

Linux live installers that work with Ubuntu 20.10 Flavors include:

### For Windows:

**Rufus**, **Etcher**, **YUMI**, **Universal**, **UNetbootin**, **Ventoy** and **Win32DiskImiger**.

### For Linux:

**Mkusb**, **Gnome-Disks**, **dd**, **Startup Disk Creator**, **Ventoy** and **Etcher**.

Answer (score 1):

I always create my Linux USB boot devices using YUMI (it offers custom options according to what distro you select, and also supports unlisted custom ISO's)
The catch is: it's a Windows application. It works fine on Wine though.
I know, it's weird that I'm recommending a Windows tool to do this, but in the past (when I was first learning about Linux) I tried a myriad of different tools, including Rufus, and Rufus itself rendered my USB flash disk broken at two different occasions, I had to use an MBR restoring utility to put the flash disk back into a working state.
After becoming tired of all the hassle and the absolute inneficiency of the linux community in providing useful information in a succint manner, I just surrendered to YUMI. It's a great tool, never had problems with it.
I can confirm that latest YUMI is working, as of November 2020.
edit: I tried UNetBootin in the past as well, did not work. And my laptop wasn't even UEFI at the time, it was standard "legacy" BIOS boot that was used in 2008.